# Is Java case-sensitive string sorting broken?

Tags: java, sorting

I’ve tried to case-sensitive sort some strings in Java and I was quite surprised by the result. Here is the code:

```
List<String> words = List.of("aLocalized", "aaLocalized", "aaaLocalized", "ALocalized", "AALocalized", "AAALocalized");
System.out.println(words.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

And here is the result:
AAALocalized AALocalized ALocalized aLocalized aaLocalized aaaLocalized

To me this doesn’t look right. Why for small letters `a` comes before `aa` and `aa` comes before `aaa`, but for capital letters `AAA` comes before `AA` and `AA` comes before `A`?

Comment: it gives you the correct result. what you expect AAL should come before AAA?

Comment: In case sensitive sorting uppercase letters always come before any lowercase letters. That's why `"aL"` comes before `"aa"` because `"L"` comes before `"a"`.

Comment: "Is Java case-sensitive string sorting broken?" No.

Comment: It looks like you expect the result that case-**in**sensitive sorting will give you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re sorted by the numeric codepoint of each character.

Each character in your Strings has a numeric codepoint, which is specified by the Unicode specification.  The ordering of the first 128 codepoints of Unicode is called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set).  As you can see in that table, uppercase letters have lower codepoint numbers than lowercase characters, so uppercase letters always come before lowercase letters when sorting.

For example, `A` is codepoint 41 (in hexadecimal), while `a` is 61.  So `A` comes before `a`.

If you want your strings to be sorted in dictionary order, use a [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html):

```
System.out.println(
    words.stream().sorted(Collator.getInstance())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you maybe fail to realize is that all capital letters come before small letters. So a `List.of("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c");` would result in `A B C a b c`